# How can I get a <p> element in a <td>?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to get a "p" element which is inside a "td". How can I get it? My code is:

```
 <td id="mytd"> 
    <p> aaaa </p>
    <p> bbbbb </p>
    <p id="myp"> cccc </p> 
 </td>
```

I can get the td using. `document.getElementById("mytd")`, but I don't know how to get the p with `id="myp"`.

Comment: do you have another element having id="myp" somewhere in other parts of your document? id must be unique for the whole document, otherwise getElementById() may not work.

Comment: Why doesn't `document.getElementById("myp");` work? What's the error? What's it returning?

Answer (score 7):

Just use exactly the same code `getElementById`, but use the ID of the `<p>` instead of the `<td>`:

```
var p = document.getElementById("myp");
p.style.background = "#000";
p.style.color= "#FFF";
```

[Here's a jsFiddle showing it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/kqgXU/1/)

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but it didn't get the value of "p" when I am doing this.

Comment: @novellino: I think what you want is: `var p = document.getElementById("myp").innerHTML;`

Comment: @novellino - Do you want the content of the p? Or do you want the actual p element from the DOM? Updated my answer as per @captaintokyo's comment.

Comment: Actually I want to get the p element in order to change something in the style of it.

Comment: @novellino - It should just be: `var p = document.getElementById("myp");`. So what exactly isn't working? What's the error? I updated my answer and provided a working example for you to look at.

Comment: I figured out something else finally, with jQuery for making it work.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("myp")`

If you output valid HTML, your IDs you use for DOM elements should be unique for the whole document. Thus, you can do something as simple as this. If this doesn't work (got more elements with this ID), deal with that problem instead. IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this jQuery as well :

```
var p = $("td#mytd p#myp");
```

Then you can get html or text `p.html(); or p.text();`

**Correction :**

I don't think `td#anyid`(tag name is redundant) is necessary because IDs are unique in document you need those only if you were using classes so I think should do(if you use jQuery that is) :

```
var p = $("#myp");
```

Answer (score -1):

with jQuery

```
$("p[id$='myp']")
```

Comment: a) typo (you're selecting 'a' elements instead of 'p's) b) what's with the 'end of string' selector? c) why do this with an attribute selector anyway (why not just $('#myp') ?) d) asker doesn't mention jQuery e) It's jQuery, not jquery ;-)

Comment: :D yep ... my fault ... a->p and discussion about selecting only id and element->id in Jquery is thing that I don't want open here...